# Два сайта на одном IP адресе второй поддом

Tags: apache

Есть 2 домена: test.ru и site2.test.ru
Оба домена привязаны к одному внешнему IP адресу
test.ru в данный момент открывается на порту http/80 и https/443
Оба сайта размещены на одном сервере, где установлен apache2.4

Нужно сделать так, чтобы site2.test.ru тоже была доступно из вне на порту http/80 и https/443 на том же внешнем IP адресе, где test.ru.

Comment: А зачем в тегах nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Может **nginx** используется? Если используется, то тогда надо указать что он используется

Comment: Но вообще это стандартная задача со стандартным решением из документации